# Probability measures from states on $C(X)$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space and let $\omega$ be a state on $C(X)$. I know by Riesz representation theorem that states on $C(X)$ corresponds to probability measures on $X$ and vice versa. Given a probability measure $\mu$, I know how to construct the state, it is given by 
$\omega_m(f)=\int f d\mu$. How to go the other direction?
That is given a state $\omega$, is it true that the measure corresponding to it can be calculated by $\mu(B)=\omega(1_B)$, where $B$ is a Borel measurable set and $_B$ is the indicator function. Is indicator functions are continuous? At least for Borel measurable sets?

Comment: Indicator functions are not continuous and there is no simple construction of $\mu$. In particular when $X$ is connected **no indicator function is continuous** except the two trivial ones corresponding to the empty set and $X$.

Answer (score 1):

One standard way that I know of to go back from a state (functional) $\omega$ on $C(X)$ to a measure, is to consider Urysohn functions for pairs $(K,U)$, where $K$ is compact and $U$ open with $K \subseteq U$; such function are continuous $X \to [0,1]$, are $\equiv 1$ on $K$ and $\equiv 0$ outside $U$, and then for such a function $\omega(f)$ approaches what $\mu(K)$ should be for $U$ "closer to $K$". Note that local compactness of $X$ is need to have enough of such pairs; usually we can take infima of $\omega(f)$ for such Urysohn functions, and when we have values for $\mu(K)$, inner regularity of $\mu$ tells us what the value on all Borel sets of $X$ should be, etc.